# Apache solr startup script

Tags: solr

i have a little issue to take Solr to production. I use Solr 5.3

I have a bash script to start the Solr server. Solr Server should be running as non root user solr. 
My bash script to run solr server with my config and data folder.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

export SOLR_LOGS_DIR=/home/hybris/solr/log
export LOG4J_PROPS=/home/hybris/solr/solr/conf/log4j.properties
export SOLR_PID_DIR=/home/hybris/solr/data

/home/hybris/solr/solr/bin/solr start -d /home/hybris/solr/solr/server -s /home/hybris/solr/solr/conf -p 8983 -m 7g -Dsolr.log.dir=/home/hybris/solr/log -DconfigSetBaseDir=/home/hybris/solr/solr/conf/configsets -DcoreRootDirectory=/home/hybris/solr/data/cores
```

I want to use the solr starup script to do this. 
On the solr.in.sh i can not found set this variable

```
DconfigSetBaseDir=/home/hybris/solr/solr/conf/configsets
DcoreRootDirectory=/home/hybris/solr/data/cores
```

Solr Server is starting as non root user solr, without config and wrong data folder. 
Can Everyone explain how to use this two variables in solr.in.sh.

> https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Taking+Solr+to+Production
>   Environment overrides include file

now my content from  /etc/default/solr.in.sh

```
# Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
# contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
# this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
# The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
# (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
# the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.

# By default the script will use JAVA_HOME to determine which java
# to use, but you can set a specific path for Solr to use without
# affecting other Java applications on your server/workstation.
#SOLR_JAVA_HOME=""

# Increase Java Heap as needed to support your indexing / query needs
SOLR_HEAP="7g"

# Expert: If you want finer control over memory options, specify them directly
# Comment out SOLR_HEAP if you are using this though, that takes precedence
#SOLR_JAVA_MEM="-Xms512m -Xmx512m"

# Enable verbose GC logging
GC_LOG_OPTS="-verbose:gc -XX:+PrintHeapAtGC -XX:+PrintGCDetails \
-XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution -XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime"

# These GC settings have shown to work well for a number of common Solr workloads
GC_TUNE="-XX:NewRatio=3 \
-XX:SurvivorRatio=4 \
-XX:TargetSurvivorRatio=90 \
-XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=8 \
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC \
-XX:+UseParNewGC \
-XX:ConcGCThreads=4 -XX:ParallelGCThreads=4 \
-XX:+CMSScavengeBeforeRemark \
-XX:PretenureSizeThreshold=64m \
-XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly \
-XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=50 \
-XX:CMSMaxAbortablePrecleanTime=6000 \
-XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled \
-XX:+ParallelRefProcEnabled"

# Set the ZooKeeper connection string if using an external ZooKeeper ensemble
# e.g. host1:2181,host2:2181/chroot
# Leave empty if not using SolrCloud
#ZK_HOST=""

# Set the ZooKeeper client timeout (for SolrCloud mode)
#ZK_CLIENT_TIMEOUT="15000"

# By default the start script uses "localhost"; override the hostname here
# for production SolrCloud environments to control the hostname exposed to cluster state
#SOLR_HOST="192.168.1.1"

# By default the start script uses UTC; override the timezone if needed
#SOLR_TIMEZONE="UTC"

# Set to true to activate the JMX RMI connector to allow remote JMX client applications
# to monitor the JVM hosting Solr; set to "false" to disable that behavior
# (false is recommended in production environments)
ENABLE_REMOTE_JMX_OPTS="false"

# The script will use SOLR_PORT+10000 for the RMI_PORT or you can set it here
# RMI_PORT=18983

# Anything you add to the SOLR_OPTS variable will be included in the java
# start command line as-is, in ADDITION to other options. If you specify the
# -a option on start script, those options will be appended as well. Examples:
#SOLR_OPTS="$SOLR_OPTS -Dsolr.autoSoftCommit.maxTime=3000"
#SOLR_OPTS="$SOLR_OPTS -Dsolr.autoCommit.maxTime=60000"
#SOLR_OPTS="$SOLR_OPTS -Dsolr.clustering.enabled=true"
SOLR_OPTS="$SOLR_OPTS -DconfigSetBaseDir=/home/hybris/solr/solr/conf/configsets
SOLR_OPTS="$SOLR_OPTS -DcoreRootDirectory=/home/hybris/solr/data/cores

# Location where the bin/solr script will save PID files for running instances
# If not set, the script will create PID files in $SOLR_TIP/bin
SOLR_PID_DIR=/home/hybris/solr/data

# Path to a directory for Solr to store cores and their data. By default, Solr will use server/solr
# If solr.xml is not stored in ZooKeeper, this directory needs to contain solr.xml
#SOLR_HOME=/home/hybris/solr/solr/conf

# Solr provides a default Log4J configuration properties file in server/resources
# however, you may want to customize the log settings and file appender location
# so you can point the script to use a different log4j.properties file
LOG4J_PROPS=/home/hybris/solr/solr/conf/log4j.properties

# Location where Solr should write logs to; should agree with the file appender
# settings in server/resources/log4j.properties
SOLR_LOGS_DIR=/home/hybris/solr/log

# Sets the port Solr binds to, default is 8983
#SOLR_PORT=8983





# Uncomment to set SSL-related system properties
# Be sure to update the paths to the correct keystore for your environment
#SOLR_SSL_KEY_STORE=etc/solr-ssl.keystore.jks
#SOLR_SSL_KEY_STORE_PASSWORD=secret
#SOLR_SSL_TRUST_STORE=etc/solr-ssl.keystore.jks
#SOLR_SSL_TRUST_STORE_PASSWORD=secret
#SOLR_SSL_NEED_CLIENT_AUTH=false
#SOLR_SSL_WANT_CLIENT_AUTH=false

# Uncomment if you want to override previously defined SSL values for HTTP client
# otherwise keep them commented and the above values will automatically be set for HTTP clients
#SOLR_SSL_CLIENT_KEY_STORE=
#SOLR_SSL_CLIENT_KEY_STORE_PASSWORD=
#SOLR_SSL_CLIENT_TRUST_STORE=
#SOLR_SSL_CLIENT_TRUST_STORE_PASSWORD=

# Settings for authentication
#SOLR_AUTHENTICATION_CLIENT_CONFIGURER=
#SOLR_AUTHENTICATION_OPTS=
```

Answer (score 0):

The Solution is very simple.

Use Monit. My issue is, i use a self written start and stop shell script.

Install Monit and then create a file in

/etc/monit/conf.d

```
  check process solr with pidfile /home/hybris/solr/data/solr-8983.pid
  start program = "/home/hybris/solr/solr_start.sh" as uid hybris and gid hybris
  stop program  = "/home/hybris/solr/solr_stop.sh" as uid hybris and gid hybris
```

Now sse what happen when you ask monit is all running?

```
monit summary
The Monit daemon 5.6 uptime: 7m

Process 'solr'                      Running
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you can't use install_solr_service.sh script to install solr.

In which we passing solr directory using option -i and data directory using option -d.

sudo bash ./install_solr_service.sh solr-6.6.0.tgz -i /opt -d /var/solr -u solr -s solr -p 8983